# VBA runtime error in using findelementsbyxpath

Tags: vba, xpath, web-crawler

```vb
xpathstring 
="/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/section/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody"
           j = 1
           trcnt = 1
           For Each ele In cd.FindElementsByClass("CI-GRID-EVEN")
                dataArr(j, 1) = ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[trcnt]/td[1]").Text
                'Debug.Print dataArr(j, 1); trcnt; j
                dataArr(j, 2) = ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[trcnt]/td[5]").Text
                dataArr(j, 3) = ele.FindElementByXPath("" + xpathstring + "/tr[trcnt]/td[2]").Text
                j = j + 1
                trcnt = trcnt + 2
           Next ele
```

There is no error for `tr[1]`, but error in using variable like `tr[trcnt]` in findelementsbyxpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `"/tr[trcnt]` you want `"/tr[" + trcnt + "]"`

Comment: Thank you so much. Fortunately I got the clue 3 days ago like you mentioned. But I got a new problems. the  array number of the class "CI-GRID-EVEN" is 63. First 10th values of the elements array are normal, but I can't find anything from the  array 11th to the last.